# How to create image target/marker for ARKit like Vuforia do?

Tags: augmented-reality, vuforia, arkit

I would like to create my own image target/marker to **use with ARKit** like Vurofia does.

I should use image analysis algorithm, detecting unique point of my markers

Vuforia generates a new image (XML+Image) with point clouds to identify each marker.

[image]
[image]
Are there alternative tools to create this? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ARKit - Is it possible to track objects like with vuforia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44817416/arkit-is-it-possible-to-track-objects-like-with-vuforia)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you integrate OpenCV with ARKit, it`s possible.

OpenCV is a powerful library which allows you to do a lot of cv tasks, besides it`s flexible and c++ based.